# Three Column Layout, Simple please!

Tags: multicolumn, cv

I am using LaTeX to write a CV and would like to be able to set 3 columns whose width I can define and be able to designate in which column certain text goes into.  Most of the answers to this question that I have found online are from pre-written packages that allow little customization.  I would just like to know if anyone can recommend a simple 3 column layout.  Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have you looked into using the `longtable` package and its eponymous environment?

Comment: Have you looked at the `parcolumns` package?  It allows you to create three columns of different widths.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with `parcolumns`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\kant[2]

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{5in}
  \begin{parcolumns}[rulebetween,colwidths={1=0.30\textwidth,2=0.4\textwidth,3=1in}]{3}
    \colchunk[1]{\raggedright\lipsum[2]}
    \colchunk[2]{\raggedright\kant[1]}
    \colchunk[3]{last column}
  \end{parcolumns}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

which results in

[image]

However, `parcolumns` will not break the columns over multiple pages.  For that you might consider using the `paracol` package or `longtable`

Here's an example using `paracol` which will split columns over multiple pages

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\kant[2]

  \setcolumnwidth{0.30\textwidth/1cm,0.4\textwidth,1in}%%
  \begin{paracol}{3}
    {\raggedright\lipsum[2]}
    \switchcolumn
    {\raggedright\kant[1]}
    \switchcolumn
    {last column}
  \end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

which results in

[image]